# Source Safe command line command "ss Add"

Tags: command-line, visual-sourcesafe

I need to add some files to the VSS through the command line, but I can't figure out how to set the destination project in the VSS?

Official description (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tszt2szw(VS.80).aspx) doesn’t have any remarks about setting the internal VSS path to add the file. By defaults it uses path which can be seen by the command "ss Project"

Could anyone please help me?

PS: I know that VSS is not the best but still it is used by some companies.

Thanks a lot in advance
Yury

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the ss CP command to set the VSS "current project" to the destination project to which you want to add the file.

Comment: Thank you ! I have been looking for this for hours now !

Comment: @ereOn Nice to know these old answers still help. :)